# assigning column range in csv file to variable using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file that has  30 columns
and I have two variables (X,y)
I want the variable y to get all the rows from column number 0
so I used

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv" )
y = df[:0]
```

this gets only the header which I don't need

and I want the variable X to get all the rows from the columns 4 to 23

```
X = df[4:23]
```

but this doesn't work because it gets all the columns from row 4 so its the opposite from what I need.

Comment: use df.iloc to get column or row by location, such as df.iloc[3:5, 0:2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled across the answer
I should be using iloc , so it should be

```
y = df.iloc[: , 0].values
X = df.iloc[ :  , 4: 23 ].values
```